# The rate of decay of $\sum_{j}(|a_{j} - T| + 1)^{-1} |a_{j}|$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

How do we find out the rate of decay of the series
\[
\sum_{j}(|a_{j} - T| + 1)^{-q} |a_{j}|^{-1}
\]
as $T \to \infty$?

Suppose that $q > 0$ and
\[
\sum_{j}|a_{j}|^{-1 - \epsilon} < \infty.
\]

Any idea? Can we maybe analyze the sum case
just by rewriting it as a suitable form?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: What kind of an estimate are you looking for?

Comment: Such as, $f(T) \ll T^{-\epsilon}$