# The order of $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} (|n - T| + 1)^{- 1} (|n| + 1)^{-1}$ as $T \to \infty$?

Tags: calculus, analysis

By an easy argument, I can prove that the sum of the title
is $\ll T^{-1/2}$ as $T \to \infty$.

But if we recall the integral version of this sum, then 
we can prove that
\[
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(|t - T| + 1)^{-1/2 - h} (|t| + 1)^{-1} dt \ll T^{-1/2}.
\]
(better improvement on $h$).

Can we generalize the integral case to the sum one?

Or can we find out a better bound for the sum of the title?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the true order would be $\ln T/T$.

Comment: And any simple argument to show it?

Answer (score 1):

A simple argument... Let's assume $T$ is a positive integer, first. Then, we have \begin{align}\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} (|n - T| + 1)^{- 1} (|n| + 1)^{-1}=&
\sum_{n<0}(|n - T| + 1)^{- 1} (|n| + 1)^{-1}+\sum^T_{n=0}(|n - T| + 1)^{- 1} (|n| + 1)^{-1}\\&+\sum_{n>T}(|n - T| + 1)^{- 1} (|n| + 1)^{-1}
\end{align}
Now, we'll estimate those three sums:
$$\sum_{n<0}(|n - T| + 1)^{- 1} (|n| + 1)=\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac1{(n+T+1)(n+1)}=\frac1T\sum^\infty_{n=1}\left(\frac1{n+1}-\frac1{n+T+1}\right),$$
where the RHS is a sort of telescoping sum, so its value is $$\frac1T\sum^{T+1}_{n=2}\frac1n=\frac1T\,(H_{T+1}-1),$$ where $H_n$ are the [harmonic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number).
\begin{align}\sum^T_{n=0}(|n - T| + 1)^{- 1} (|n| + 1)^{-1}=&\sum^T_{n=0}\frac1{(T+1-n)(n+1)}=\frac1{T+2}\sum^T_{n=0}\left(\frac1{n+1}+\frac1{T+1-n}\right)\end{align}
Here. the RHS is clearly $$\frac2{T+2}\,H_{T+1}.$$
Finally, $$\sum_{n>T}(|n - T| + 1)^{- 1} (|n| + 1)^{-1}=\sum^\infty_{n=T+1}\frac1{(n-T+1)(n+1)}=\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac1{(n+T+1)(n+1)}$$ with the translation $n-T\to n$, the same value as the first sum.
In total, we obtain $$\left(\frac2T+\frac2{T+2}\right)\,H_{T+1}-\frac2T,$$ and that's clearly $O\left(\dfrac{\ln T}T\right)$ due to the asymptotic behavior of harmonic numbers. Since it's easy to show that the original sum is monotone decreasing as a function of $T$ (hint: derivative), the same is true for non-integer $T$.

Comment: Thanks for the simple answer.

Comment: If you have the time, you are invited to answer [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2578477/the-rate-of-decay-of-sum-ja-j-t-1-1-a-j)  also.